# Manipulate array of hashes into grouped hashes with arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
[
    {
        "June" => { "A" => { 3 => 48.4 } }
    },
    {
        "January" => { "C" => { 2 => 88.0} }
    },
    {
        "January"=> { "B" => { 2 => 44.0} }
    },
    {
        "January"=> { "C" => { 4 => 48.8} }
    }
]
```

I need to group each similar hash key into an array of the subsequent values like the following:

```
{
    "June" => [{ "A" => [{ 3 => 48.4 }]] },
    "January" => [
        { "B" => [{ 2 => 44.0}],
        { "C" => [{ 2 => 88.0}, { 4 => 48.8}],
        ] }
}
```

I am looking for an efficient method of grouping these elements. Can anyone help me master this hash of hashes?

I am trying to avoid looping through the base array and grouping manually. I was hoping that `map` (or some other enumerable method) might give what I want. When I used `reduce(Hash.new, :merge)`, it came close but it used the last hash for each month key instead of adding it to an array.

Comment: In the hash you wish to construct shouldn't the value of the key `"January"` be `[{ "B" => [{ 2 => 44.0}], "C" => [{ 2 => 88.0}, { 4 => 48.8}]`? If so, is there any reason you want to enclose each hash in an array? Would the following not be better as `"January"`'s value: `{ "B"=>{ 2=>44.0 }, "C"=>{ 2=>88.0, 4=>48.8 } }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I added the following after gaining a clearer understanding of the question. My original answer is below.

Here is the OP's array of hashes, modified slightly.

```
arr = [{ "June"   =>{ "A"=>{ 3=>48.4 } } },
       { "January"=>{ "C"=>{ 2=>88.0 } } },
       { "January"=>{ "B"=>{ "D"=>{ 2=>44.0 } } } },
       { "January"=>{ "C"=>{ 2=>10.0 } } },
       { "January"=>{ "C"=>{ 4=>48.8 } } }]
```

The hash to be constructed appears to be the following.

```
{ "June"   =>[{ "A"=>[{ 3=>48.4 }] }],
  "January"=>[{ "B"=>[{ "D"=>[{ 2=>44.0 }] }] }],
                "C"=>[{ 2=>98.0, 4=>48.8 }] }] }
```

Note that `88.0 + 10.0 #=> 98.0` in `2=>98.0`.

Observe that all the arrays within `arr` contain a single element, a hash. That being the case, those arrays serve no useful purpose. I therefore suggest the following hash be constructed instead:

```
{ "June"   =>{ "A"=>{ 3=>48.4 } },
  "January"=>{ "B"=>{ "D"=>{ 2=>44.0 } } },
               "C"=>{ 2=>98.0, 4=>48.8 } } }
```

This can be produced with the following recursive method.

```
def recurse(arr)
  arr.map(&:flatten).
      group_by(&:first).
      each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
        o = v.map(&:last)
        h.update(k=>o.first.is_a?(Hash) ? recurse(o) : o.sum )
      end
 end

 recurse(arr)
   #=> {"June"=>{"A"=>{3=>48.4}},
   #    "January"=>{"C"=>{2=>98.0, 4=>48.8}, "B"=>{"D"=>{2=>44.0}}}}
```

---

(Original answer follows)

Here are two ways to obtain the desired hash. I assume that `arr` is your array of hashes.

**#1 Use the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block**

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  k, v = g.to_a.first
  h[k] << v
end
  # => {"June"=>[{"A"=>{3=>48.4}}],
  #     "January"=>[{"C"=>{2=>88.0}}, {"B"=>{2=>44.0}}, {"C"=>{4=>48.8}}]}
```

**#2 Use [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
arr.map(&:first).
    group_by(&:first).
    tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:last) } }
  # => {"June"=>[{"A"=>{3=>48.4}}],
  #     "January"=>[{"C"=>{2=>88.0}}, {"B"=>{2=>44.0}}, {"C"=>{4=>48.8}}]}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = arr.map(&:first)
  #=> [["June", {"A"=>{3=>48.4}}], ["January", {"C"=>{2=>88.0}}],
  #    ["January", {"B"=>{2=>44.0}}], ["January", {"C"=>{4=>48.8}}]]
b = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"June"=>[["June", {"A"=>{3=>48.4}}]],
  #    "January"=>[["January", {"C"=>{2=>88.0}}], ["January", {"B"=>{2=>44.0}}],
  #                ["January", {"C"=>{4=>48.8}}]]}
c = b.tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:last) } }
  #=> {"June"=>[{"A"=>{3=>48.4}}],
  #    "January"=>[{"C"=>{2=>88.0}}, {"B"=>{2=>44.0}}, {"C"=>{=>48.8}}]}
```

Let me elaborate the last step. Inside `tap`'s block, we compute the following.

```
h = b
d = h.keys
  #=> ["June", "January"]
```

The first element of `d` is passed to `each`'s block and the block variable is assigned to that element.

```
k = d.first
  #=> "June"
```

The block calculation is as follows.

```
e = h[k]
  #=> [["June", {"A"=>{3=>48.4}}]]
f = e.map(&:last)
  #=> [{"A"=>{3=>48.4}}]
h[k] = f
  #=> [{"A"=>{3=>48.4}}]
b #=> {"June"=>[{"A"=>{3=>48.4}}],
  #    "January"=>[["January", {"C"=>{2=>88.0}}],
  #                ["January", {"B"=>{2=>44.0}}],
  #                ["January", {"C"=>{4=>48.8}}]]}
```

Next, `d[1]` ("January") is passed to `each`'s block and similar calculations are performed.

Rather than using [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) I could have written

```
h = arr.map(&:first).
    group_by(&:first)
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:last) }
h
```

`tap` merely avoids the creation of local variable `h` and the need to have a final line equal to `h`.

Comment: Tried the second method - it worked but it removed the 2nd tier keys from my code:  ... "January"=>[{2=>88.0}, {2=>44.0}, {4=>48.8}]. (but so fricken close).

Other than that - its prefect for what I was looking for...I will try the first option.

Comment: First way (with the each block) results in the same as the second method....So close to perfection....Any idea why its removing the 2nd tier?

Comment: Unless it something else in my code thats removing it - this is on a chained set of maps etc that are generating the hash in the first place (which is why the second technique is preferred).

Comment: I just isolated the code fragment and used the array sample above, and it did the same thing, removed the second tier of hash keys from the result.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, it worked properly after all.  I will debug more clearly.

Comment: Whoops! I misread the question. Let me know in a comment you've read this. I will then delete my answer, fix it, and undelete.

Comment: Consider it read.  (although your original answer was correct, I've had it working for a couple of hours) - although I do need to get the sum of all the values, is there an easy way to do this, I can't seem to get my '.inject' method working right.

Comment: In that case I'll just add a bit. What do you mean by summing the values? Do you mean you wish to sum the elements of  `[48.4, 88.0, 44.0, 48.8]`? If so, `arr.map { |h| h.to_a.first.last.values.first.values.first }.sum #=> 229.2`. To see what's happening here, execute `arr.map { |h| h.to_a }`, then `arr.map { |h| h.to_a.first }`, then `arr.map { |h| h.to_a.first.last }` etc.